# How to use schema for multiple sqlite db for Zend_Db_Table

Tags: zend-framework, sqlite, schema, zend-db-table

So I have multiple sqlite database.
/path/database1.db
/path/database2.db

When i make a Zend_Db_Table for it, how do I specify which db to use?

```
class Application_Model_DbTable_User extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
    protected $_schema = 'database1.db';
    protected $_name = 'user';
}
```

This don't seem to work.

My current solution,
I use multidb and extend Zend_Db_Table_Abstract and have an _setup overide like

```
...... Bootstrap - then use the multidb key for _database
$multiDb = $this->getPluginResource('multidb');
$multiDb->init();
Zend_Registry::set('db', $multiDb);
...... My/Table.php
class My_Table extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
    public function _setup()
    {
        if($this->_database) {
            $this->_setAdapter(Zend_Registry::get('db')->getDb($this->_database));
        }
    }
}
....... DbTables/Table1.php
class Application_Model_DbTable_Table1 extends My_Table
{
    protected $_database = 'database1';
    protected $_name = 'table1';
}
```

But I'm just wondering maybe there is already a way.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest thing I can think of is to override `Zend_Db_Table_Abstract::_setupDatabaseAdapter()`, eg

```
protected function _setupDatabaseAdapter()
{
    if (!$this->_db) {
        $multiDb = Zend_Registry::get('multidb');
        $this->_setAdapter($multiDb->getDb('database1'));
    }
}
```

You won't need to add anything to your Bootstrap as application resources are automatically registered in `Zend_Registry`.

I'd even go further and place this into a custom abstract class, eg

```
abstract class Application_Model_DbTable_Abstract extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
    protected function _setupDatabaseAdapter()
    {
        // as above
    }
}
```

Then have your concrete `DbTable` classes extend this.

Comment: It doesn't look like Zend_Registry auto adds my resources. anything special I need to turn on? This is the same as what I already have. I guess maybe there isn't a direct way yet. THanks

Comment: @Lasiaf My mistake. Whilst `Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract` uses `Zend_Registry` internally, it's not the globally available instance.